# R - Reading data from a csv and performing linear regression

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am reading data from a csv and using the library dplyr in R.
The csv file contains 9 columns and some values in the columns can be missing and this needs to be dealt with:

```
Price | Bedroom | Space | Room | Lot | Tax | Bathroom | Garage | Condition

Price = price of the house 
Bedroom = # of Bedroom 
Space = size of the house
Room = # of rooms
Lot = width of a lot 
Tax = annual tax
Bathroom = # of bathrooms 
Garage = # of garages 
Condition = 1 is good, 0 otherwise
```

Price is the dependant variable and I am using other variables as predictors using a linear regression model. I am writing a function which takes one argument which is a path to the csv file and this function should return a named list of 2 objects:

1 = summary_list -> this will be a named list of length 3 containing :

```
1a = statistics (numeric vector of length = 5) -> mean, standard deviation, median, minimum and maximum for Tax for all houses with 2 bathrooms and 5 bedrooms
1b = data_frame -> a data frame with observations for Space > 800 and ordered by decreasing Price
1c = number_of_observations -> a numeric value for the number of observations for which the value of Lot is >= 4th 5-quantile of this variable.
```

2 = regression_list -> this will be a named list of length 2 containing :

```
2a = model_parameters(numeric vector of length = 9) -> this should give the model parameters. The first element should be named Intercept and all other should have their respective variable e.g Bedroom , Space
2b = price_prediction -> a numeric value which shows the prediction of the price for a house with: 3 bedrooms, 1500 space, 8 rooms, lot = 40, tax = 1000, 2 bathrooms, garage = 1, condition = 0
```

This is how I am starting the function but I am completely lost:

```
library(dplyr)

analyse_and_fit_lrm <- function(file_path) {
  df <- read.csv(file_path)
}
```

Comment: What's the question exactly, how to build a linear regression model, or how to package it into a function, or both, or something else? Narrow down the steps—figure out how to build your model, then figure out how to extract the summary stats you want, then figure out how to make predictions, then build a function. Beyond that, we'd need a [mcve]

Comment: I am trying to build a linear regression model and package the results into a function

Comment: Right, but what's the question? What isn't working?

Comment: I am not sure how to go ahead with this.

Comment: As @camille hints: show us how you would do the individual components (i.e., edit your question). Then we can help you with the packaging. If you don't know how to derive the individual components and can't figure it out by doing some research, then ask another question or edit this one to focus on that specific problem.